# Adding css class to WooCommerce Filter By Products Attribute widget

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I'm using the WooCommerce "Filter By Products Attribute" widget to create product filters on the category page. This is a standard widget that comes out of the box with WooCommerce.

I've added this widget multiple times for each attribute - which allows users to filter by size, colour, etc.

When someone clicks on an attribute, the page reloads and the products are then filtered by their selection.

However, I want to hide the filters which are not active, and show the active filters. Clicking on an inactive filter would expand it open, so someone can make a selection. But after making a selection and the page reloading, that widget should then remain open. See image below:

[image: Filter image]

Essentially I want to add a class name to the active filters.

We're altering the widget markup as follows:

```
// Change widget markup
add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', function($params) {
    $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<section class="widget">';
    $params[0]['after_widget'] = '</div></section>';
    $params[0]['before_title'] =  '<h2 class="widget-title">' ;
    $params[0]['after_title'] =  '</h2><div>' ;
    return $params;
});
```

In the case of the "Filter By Products Attribute" widget this results in the following markup:

```
<section class="widget">
    <h2 class="widget-title">Color</h2>
    <div>
        <ul class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list">
            <li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item--chosen chosen">
                <a rel="nofollow" href="xxx/?query_type_color=or">Red</a>
                <span class="count">(2)</span>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm using CSS to hide all of the filters:

```
.widget > div { display: none; }
```

I'm then using jQuery to unhide the active filter widgets:

```
// Mark widget as active
$(".widget .chosen").closest(".widget > div").show();
```

However, I don't really want to unhide the active filters with jQuery as it results in a shift in the layout as the page loads. I want to include an `active` class on the active filter markup (without using jQuery) so that the resulting markup is:

```
<section class="widget">
    <h2 class="widget-title">Color</h2>
    <div class="active">
```

So far I've been unable to find any way of accessing the widget itself, figuring out if it's active, and adding a class name to its parent wrapper.

Comment: If there is no hook/filter inside the widget or you can't overwrite any template, you must program your own widget or use jQuery. I see no other way here.